# Storing the changes made to MYSQL DB and updating the changes to another MYSQL db on a different server

Tags: mysql, database, apache

I have two servers, same Database. If I add a new row/column in DB1(Server1) or make changes to existing rows in DB1. The same should be updated to MYSQL DB2(Server2).

Comment: [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html)

Comment: Does it only flow from DB1 to DB2? Is DB2 read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of mysql you're running, **replication** might be the answer for you.  In recent versions it's "out of the box" although I've never actually configured it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html).

It enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).